# How to pixelize and unpixelize an UIImage or UIImageview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I would like to pixelize and unpixelize an `UIImage` or an `UIImageview` using Swift but I have no idea on how can I do that.

Maybe using effects, layer or something like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very easy task on iOS.

### Pixelation

Your can use the [CIPixellate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPixellate) Core Image [Filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/index.html).

```
func pixellated(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    guard let
        ciImage = CIImage(image: image),
        filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate") else { return nil }
    filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    guard let output = filter.outputImage else { return nil }
    return UIImage(CIImage: output)
}
```

Result

[image]

The default `inputScale` value is `8`. However you can increase or decrease the effect manually setting the parameter.

```
filter.setValue(8, forKey: "inputScale")
//              ^
//         change this
```

### Extension

You can also define the following extension

```
extension UIImage {
    func pixellated(scale: Int = 8) -> UIImage? {
        guard let
            ciImage = UIKit.CIImage(image: self),
            filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate") else { return nil }
        filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        filter.setValue(scale, forKey: "inputScale")
        guard let output = filter.outputImage else { return nil }
        return UIImage(CIImage: output)
    }
}
```

[image]

### Unpixelation

The mechanism is exactly the same, you just need to use a different filter. You can find the full list of filters [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter) (but take a look at which params are available/required for each filter). I think the [CIGaussianBlur](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIGaussianBlur) can do the job.

Of course don't expect to be able to input a low resolution superpixellated image and get an high definition one. This technology is available only in X-Files :D

---

*The Mushroom image has been taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Supermushroom.png).*

Comment: Thank you very much!! Have a nice day!

Comment: @appzYourLife Thank you for this great tutorial. Do you have any idea how to apply a CIFilter to a regular UIView without converting the UIView to an UIImage before?

Comment: Is it normal the non-symmetric big white circle?

Comment: @Jaume I think yes. The circle in the original image ha asymmetric shadow.